# how to run google bigquery locally outside gcp or google colab notebooks?

Tags: google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run google bigquery in jupyter notebook on a local host on my pc but turns out that its not working,whereas its working fine in google vms in gcp and google colab notebooks.

Tried everything but nothing seems to work.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

ModuleNotFoundErro Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1035661e8528> in <module>
----> 1 from google.cloud import bigquery

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

Comment: Sorry if this is an obvious question but Have you installed the bigquery library? "pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery"? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter might be useful.

Comment: Agree with @MicahKornfield, first step should be following [guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) and being able to run a simple query from a python script.

Comment: @MicahKornfield thank-you so much bro, but now stucked at the authentication part. please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can connect to BigQuery from an environment which is outside GCP.
You need to setup two things:

1. Bigquery client library of your choice of language. Looking at the above code, it looks like you want to use python. You can install Bigquery python client lib by running

   `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery`
2. Authentication to BigQuery -

a. Get your GCP creds by running following command:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

This should create a credential JSON file at location "~/.config/gcloud/"

b. You can set an environment variable pointing to the JSON creds file on the command line

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json"
```

Or, you can set the above environment variable in your python program by adding the following lines:

```
import os 
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] =
 '~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but i am not able to authenticate, please help. the code provided by you says syntax error. I desperately need help on this

Comment: Yes, please provide the command you are running to authenticate and the error.
and which command is throwing syntax error?

Comment: 2nd command showing , invalid syntax in jupter notebook, also i have one json file with credentials installed locally on my pc

Comment: Are you doing copy-paste of this command or typing it?
`os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 
 '~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json'` this is a single line.

Comment: i typed but getting this message."EOL while scanning string literal".  also i am having doubt that how will it identify a particular credential json file for a project ?

Comment: credentials are tied to your email address (or service account if you use) and that can be used to all the projects you have access to. which python version you are running? It's working for me on Python 2.7

Comment: sir, i want to make it clear that i am using it on local host. so nowhere email is associated. i am using python 3.7

Comment: When you run gcloud auth command, it will ask you to provide your email creds so that it can generate a json file for you

Comment: can i have your no. please because i understand this is going to hectic for you

Comment: Can you list down the steps your are trying with exact error for exact step? From previous reply, it looked to me that your ran gcloud command successful and was facing issue when setting up environment variable. Screenshot would help

Comment: These blogs may help you - https://medium.com/john-lewis-software-engineering/authenticating-jupyter-notebook-against-bigquery-957884f78527 and https://jingsblog.com/2018/11/27/connect-your-jupyter-notebook-to-the-bigquery/

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1c_ytVgt_5u4-Z6LFP7ip5YQxSh9isp0o?usp=sharing sir i uploaded the screeshots in this link

Comment: `gcloud auth login` - this is a Unix command and you need to run on your local system or using command module. This is not python command so cant be run simply as it is in jupyter notebook.

Alternatively, one blog suggests running 

"import pydata_google_auth
credentials = pydata_google_auth.get_user_credentials(
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'],
)" 
 to get creds in python


Try following https://medium.com/john-lewis-software-engineering/authenticating-jupyter-notebook-against-bigquery-957884f78527

Comment: this one also giving syntax error, but medium blog's approach seems promising. wll let you know. thankyou soooooo much for your patience and time.

Comment: no worries. once you get credential setup then it should be all good. feel free to accept this answer if it helps to solve your problem.

Comment: so after following the steps from the blog, everything is working fine now. Thankyou so much for your help.

Comment: Great to hear to that you are able to past your errors. Feel free to accept answer to help others

Comment: accepted. But beginner so vote wont count for now. :(

Comment: No worries. Marking working answers will help others facing similar issues